# Edit JavaScript configurations at run time

Tags: javascript, json

I have a configuration file in database(postgres) for each user. This file is actually a javascript which is loaded at run time. Content is in following format:

```
user.config1= {
    name1 : value1,     
    name2 : value2,
    name3 : value3,
};
user.config2= {
    name1 : value1,     
    name2 : value2,
    name3 : value3,
};
```

I need to create a UI where these values can be changed and updated by the user at run time. I have following queries-
1. Is there a library which I can use for this purpose?
2. If I do it manually, how can I replace only the changed values?

Please let me know if I am not clear in explaining my issue.

Comment: PS: You should always write JavaScript without a space so that people don't confuse it with Java, which is another language.

Answer (score 0):

The configs should live in memory when loaded and then you can temporary change them (this is not change the config files), if you want to override the config by UI you should use database to store those configs.